# What is the difference between those 2 events in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

What is the difference between `<catalog_category_save_after>` and `<catalog_category_save_commit_after>` in Magento?

I'm going to create a new module and i have to decide in which of those two events to hang my observer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The category (and all other objects) are saved inside a transaction. The event `catalog_category_save_after` is triggered inside the transaction. So any error that might appear in the observers of this event will trigger a rollback.

The event `catalog_category_save_commit_after` is triggered after the transaction is commit-ed. So any error inside the observers for this event will not trigger a rollback for the category save.

Comment: ,can you  tell me what parameters are getting in catalog_category_save_commit_after event

Comment: @AmitBera. The current category is passed as an argument to the event.  You can get it like this: `$observer->getEvent()->getCategory()` or `$observer->getEvent()->getDataObject()`. Both return the same thing.

Comment: @marius 'catalog_category_save_commit_after' is the same event available in magento2?

Comment: @Sathish I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

event is fired after commit that means this observer can be used to signal success of SQl.

while  does not guarantee that there wouldn't be any roll back.Here while writing a observer we cant take for granted that whatever sql is fired will not be rolled back.

In short if you want to add an observer will some specific features that should collect after succees(comit) then use catalog_category_save_commit_after.